# Is it possible for a PC to use two net connections simultaneously?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, internet, tcp

We have two net connections in our office - a 10mb Wired DSL provider and a 3mb Wireless backup provider. The wireless is a backup, but it has the advantage of 3mb upload speeds whereas the wired is only around 256k up.

I would really like to be able to connect to both connections on my PC (one through Ethernet and one through Wifi) and be able to assign certain apps to each connection. This way I could set upload heavy apps (like dropbox) to use only the wireless backup connection and still have the download speed of the DSL for browsing etc.

Is this even possible? I've spoken to our office network admin and he's never heard of this.

FYI: I'm on Windows 8 Enterprise and my machine has both wired and wireless networking. The wifi chip is on a separate PCI card.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have two adapters, you can probably bridge them.

1. Open Network and Sharing Center, go to Change adapter settings.
2. Highlight the two adapters, Right-click and choose Bridge connections.

That might do it, not sure about the per app settings though...

### EDIT

This application may do what you want:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/force-specific-applications-internet-connections-forcebindip-windows/

Comment: couldn't ask for a clearer answer than that, thanks!

Comment: Bridging two connections would have no effect towards determining which of them is used for communication. Uploads would still go through the interface associated with the default route.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин That's why I gave the link to the application.

Comment: I dont think bridging is the solution at all. Please read about gateways, and having two gateways and load balancing between them.

Comment: this question has now been viewed 1000 times, so I thought I should add that I never did get this working